# dropdown button get cutoff by responsive table in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

a strange issue in bootstrap 3 responsive table combined with dropdown button.

attached are two images that demonstrate the issue, if you click the last dropdown button, it's being cut by the table frame.

everything alright here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nA9e.jpg

problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7it4F.jpg

advice anyone?

Thank you,
Roman

Comment: can you please include your html and css code so we can see what's causing this.

Comment: I see the issue looks to be the overflow on the table-responsive container. You could possibly try setting it's `overflow-y:visible` as an override to the default--but that should only come into play on small screens (`@media screen and (max-width: 767px)`) since that is where it's set `hidden` in the default css...